# iOS6 rotate methods not called when launching in landscape

Tags: objective-c, ios5, rotation, ios6

Let me start off by saying I'm not having a problem when rotating views in iOS6 after the app is open. This issue is only happening for me when the app is launched for the first time while in landscape. The new **shouldAutorotate** and **supportedInterfaceOrientations** methods are both called when launched, however none of the rotation methods are called, like **willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:**. (shouldAutorotate is always returning YES, and supportedInterfaceOrientations is always returning UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll)

In iOS5, the 'first' orientation to landscape on launch was taken care of automatically. Is there an explanation for why the device wouldn't call this first landscape rotation in iOS6? (The view controller I'm checking is the root controller of the window/app delegate).

Thanks in advance for any help with and insight into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that since the interface is not actually rotating, that the method isn't being called.

If you want to do some setup based on the orientation, have you thought of using the view controller's `intefaceOrientation` property?

Comment: Good point. I haven't looked at using interfaceOrientation in something like viewDidLoad to do what I want. I was always relying on that first rotation to be called. I'll see if I can get that to work the way I want.

Comment: Yep, ended up being a simple fix. I just moved some of my initialization to a new method and had it called on load based on the current interfaceOrientation value. Accepting this as my answer, though I'm still curious as to why the rotate methods don't get called when launched anymore. But hey, problem fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You should now use the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method and not `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`. The reason is because `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` is not guaranteed to be called in a number of situations.

This is stated in the [iOS6 release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012166-CH1-SW19) among other places.

Comment: I'm actually planning some rewrites that will make better use of viewWillLayoutSubviews since, as you say, it is the more reliable place for...well...laying out subviews. When I started I had little knowledge of how it (along with almost everything iOS) should be properly utilized. Thanks for the reminder in the release notes.